# SpringBoot Camel SendBody() routes not sending

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm trying to create a SpringBoot Camel application (for testing). I've configured the SpringBoot and Camel-Spring. And it seems that it's working, but somehow it is failing in the sending of the data to activemq (via SendBody).

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)"/>
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true"/>
    <property name="watchTopicAdvisories" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
      init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" allowUseOriginalMessage="false">
    <jmxAgent id="agent" disabled="true"/>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:a" />
        <to uri="activemq:queue:ingest.Queue" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

The main app
It fails at the template.sendBody()

```
package com.sis.klaver;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
}

@Autowired
private CamelContext camelContext;

@Bean
public String DoThis(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
    template.sendBody("direct:a", "blah blah blah");

    return "one";
}
}
```

Error Message

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.3.RELEASE)

2017-01-13 16:17:25.565  INFO 13984 --- [           main] com.sis.klaver.MainApp                   : Starting MainApp on Lenovo-PC with PID 13984 (D:\newklaver\cameldemo\target\classes started by User in D:\newklaver\cameldemo)
2017-01-13 16:17:25.567  INFO 13984 --- [           main] com.sis.klaver.MainApp                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-01-13 16:17:25.615  INFO 13984 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3c407114: startup date [Fri Jan 13 16:17:25 SGT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-01-13 16:17:26.629  INFO 13984 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$670d656] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-01-13 16:17:27.058  INFO 13984 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-01-13 16:17:27.072  INFO 13984 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-01-13 16:17:27.074  INFO 13984 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2017-01-13 16:17:27.176  INFO 13984 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-01-13 16:17:27.176  INFO 13984 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1565 ms
2017-01-13 16:17:27.316  INFO 13984 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-01-13 16:17:27.320  INFO 13984 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-13 16:17:27.320  INFO 13984 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-13 16:17:27.320  INFO 13984 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-13 16:17:27.320  INFO 13984 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-13 16:17:27.816  INFO 13984 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.converter.DefaultTypeConverter   : Loaded 190 type converters
2017-01-13 16:17:27.835  WARN 13984 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DoThis' defined in com.sis.klaver.MainApp: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.String]: Factory method 'DoThis' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Lenovo-PC-58679-1484295447423-0-2]
2017-01-13 16:17:27.836  INFO 13984 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
2017-01-13 16:17:27.847  INFO 13984 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 
2017-01-13 16:17:27.848  INFO 13984 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.011 seconds
2017-01-13 16:17:27.850  INFO 13984 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-01-13 16:17:27.859  INFO 13984 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-01-13 16:17:27.864 ERROR 13984 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DoThis' defined in com.sis.klaver.MainApp: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.String]: Factory method 'DoThis' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Lenovo-PC-58679-1484295447423-0-2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sis.klaver.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.String]: Factory method 'DoThis' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Lenovo-PC-58679-1484295447423-0-2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Lenovo-PC-58679-1484295447423-0-2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1779) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:677) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:515) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:511) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:163) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:168) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at com.sis.klaver.MainApp.DoThis(MainApp.java:26) [classes/:na]
    at com.sis.klaver.MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed6265d7.CGLIB$DoThis$0() ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sis.klaver.MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed6265d7$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$233a5f2b.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sis.klaver.MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed6265d7.DoThis() ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://a. Exchange[ID-Lenovo-PC-58679-1484295447423-0-2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:55) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:529) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:497) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:365) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:497) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:225) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:144) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:161) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    ... 36 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyone have any idea why it isn't working? For the documents I've read, it should work.

Thanks.

---

After adding @ImportResource... as suggest by Hassen Bennour
I get this error instead. Some how the error is still in the same place

```
2017-01-13 17:10:26.970  INFO 8960 --- [           main] com.sis.klaver.MainApp                   : Starting MainApp on Lenovo-PC with PID 8960 (D:\newklaver\cameldemo\target\classes started by User in D:\newklaver\cameldemo)
2017-01-13 17:10:26.972  INFO 8960 --- [           main] com.sis.klaver.MainApp                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-01-13 17:10:27.039  INFO 8960 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@f5ac9e4: startup date [Fri Jan 13 17:10:27 SGT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-01-13 17:10:27.648  INFO 8960 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
2017-01-13 17:10:28.767  INFO 8960 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e2eb989a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-01-13 17:10:29.146  INFO 8960 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-01-13 17:10:29.159  INFO 8960 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-01-13 17:10:29.160  INFO 8960 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2017-01-13 17:10:29.268  INFO 8960 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-01-13 17:10:29.268  INFO 8960 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2233 ms
2017-01-13 17:10:29.396  INFO 8960 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-01-13 17:10:29.399  INFO 8960 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-13 17:10:29.400  INFO 8960 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-13 17:10:29.400  INFO 8960 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-13 17:10:29.400  INFO 8960 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-13 17:10:29.843  INFO 8960 --- [           main] .a.c.c.x.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean : JMXAgent disabled
2017-01-13 17:10:29.912  INFO 8960 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.converter.DefaultTypeConverter   : Loaded 193 type converters
2017-01-13 17:10:29.931  WARN 8960 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DoThis' defined in com.sis.klaver.MainApp: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.String]: Factory method 'DoThis' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Lenovo-PC-59078-1484298629534-0-2]
2017-01-13 17:10:29.931  INFO 8960 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.1 (CamelContext: camelContext) is shutting down
2017-01-13 17:10:29.943  INFO 8960 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.1 (CamelContext: camelContext) uptime
2017-01-13 17:10:29.943  INFO 8960 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.1 (CamelContext: camelContext) is shutdown in 0.012 seconds
2017-01-13 17:10:29.945  INFO 8960 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-01-13 17:10:29.958  WARN 8960 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'camelContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@f5ac9e4 has not been refreshed yet)
2017-01-13 17:10:29.963 ERROR 8960 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DoThis' defined in com.sis.klaver.MainApp: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.String]: Factory method 'DoThis' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Lenovo-PC-59078-1484298629534-0-2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sis.klaver.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.String]: Factory method 'DoThis' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Lenovo-PC-59078-1484298629534-0-2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Lenovo-PC-59078-1484298629534-0-2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1779) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:677) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:515) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:511) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:163) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:168) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at com.sis.klaver.MainApp.DoThis(MainApp.java:23) [classes/:na]
    at com.sis.klaver.MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9dd281b.CGLIB$DoThis$0() ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sis.klaver.MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9dd281b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c209c90b.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sis.klaver.MainApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9dd281b.DoThis() ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://a. Exchange[ID-Lenovo-PC-59078-1484298629534-0-2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:55) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:529) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:497) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:365) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:497) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:225) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:144) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:161) ~[camel-core-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    ... 36 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

route direct:a is not started
add `@ImportResource` like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class MainApp {
```

**UPDATE**

remove **@Bean** and parameter if you can and call `DoThis` by another way because i think that the xml import is done later than annotated config and the sender in DoThis tries to send before that the consumer become active.

```
//@Bean
public String DoThis() {
```

**OR** update sending to block like this :

```
template.sendBody("direct:a?block=true", "blah blah blah");
```

> **block : Default=false,** Camel 2.11.1: If sending a message to a direct endpoint which has no active consumer, then we can tell the producer to block and wait for the consumer to become active.

Comment: Thanks Hassen, it solved one problem and another surfaced. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks Hassen, your codes helped me to move it along but I have encountered more problems. So after puzzling for 2 days, I've decided to abandon using Spring Boot, it is just not productive to try to do this anymore. I'm just going to create a camel-spring main and just run it.

Comment: i think that it is better to use only xml or annotated config in your case with camel